# Parse Json or Mongodata into viz.js dataset using x y coordinate?

Tags: javascript, json, mongodb, meteor

My Json data is like this:

```
[ {
    "age": 21,
    "eyeColor": "blue",
    "name": "Dejesus Thornton",
    "gender": "male",
    "registered": "2015-06-10"
  },
{
    "age": 21,
    "eyeColor": "blue",
    "name": "Dejesus Thornton",
    "gender": "male",
    "registered": "2015-06-11"
  },
{
    "age": 21,
    "eyeColor": "blue",
    "name": "Dejesus Thornton",
    "gender": "male",
    "registered": "2015-06-12"
  },
...
]
```

I parsed it into my meteor mongo collection which is like this (every item in collection is an object):

```
{
    "age": 21,
    "eyeColor": "blue",
    "name": "Dejesus Thornton",
    "gender": "male",
    "registered": "2015-06-11"
}
```

I was trying to parse this kind of data into [**viz.js**](http://visjs.org/) which accepts data like this:

```
var items = [
    {x: '2014-06-13', y: 30, group: 0},
    {x: '2014-06-14', y: 10, group: 0},
    {x: '2014-06-15', y: 15, group: 1},
    {x: '2014-06-16', y: 30, group: 1},
    {x: '2014-06-17', y: 10, group: 1},
    {x: '2014-06-18', y: 15, group: 1}
];
```

I am trying to count how many people registered at the same day or have same eye color(same thing).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's simple. Use **Array.prototype.reduce()** for counting. Assign your raw data array to a variable named **rawArray**.

```
var rawArray = [ {
    "age": 21,
    "eyeColor": "blue",
    "name": "Dejesus Thornton",
    "gender": "male",
    "registered": "2015-06-10"
  },
{
    "age": 21,
    "eyeColor": "blue",
    "name": "Dejesus Thornton",
    "gender": "male",
    "registered": "2015-06-11"
  },
{
    "age": 21,
    "eyeColor": "blue",
    "name": "Dejesus Thornton",
    "gender": "male",
    "registered": "2015-06-12"
  },
...
]
```

Then, group by specific property of each item. Like this:

```
function groupByProperty(array, property) {
  var newObject = array.reduce(function(counters, item) {
    if(!counters[item[property]]) {
      counters[item[property]] = 1;
    }
    else {
      counters[item[property]] += 1;
    }
    return counters;
  }, {});
  return Object.keys(newObject).map(function(x) {
    var obj = {
      x: x,
      y: newObject[x],
      group: 0
    };
    return obj; 
  });
}

console.log(groupByProperty(rawArray, 'registered')); // Group by 'registered'.

//  [ {
//    group: 0,
//    x: "2015-06-10",
//    y: 1
//  }, {
//    group: 0,
//    x: "2015-06-11",
//    y: 1
//  }, {
//    group: 0,
//    x: "2015-06-12",
//    y: 1
//  }]

console.log(groupByProperty(rawArray, 'eyeColor')); // Group by 'eyeColor'.

//  [{
//    group: 0,
//    x: "blue",
//    y: 3
//  }]
```